# PWA - How to cache html pages (not only js, css...)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, laravel-mix, workbox

If I use,

```
registerRoute(
    new RegExp('.*'),
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'all',
    })
);
```

it will work and cache all the pages with all the assets. So if I refresh the page in offline mode, it works.

But apparently it's not a good idea to cache ALL! So I want to cache `js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2` and of course the `html` as well.

So if I use

```
registerRoute(
    new RegExp('(\.(js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$)'), // <<== how to add html type here to be cached?
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'all',
    })
);
```

and refresh the page while it's in offline mode, it can't view the page since it hasn't cached.

I'm using `Vuejs`, `Mix`, `Workbox`.

Comment: In the workbox config you can set the variable `globPatterns: [ "**/*.{js,css,html}",           "**/*.{png,svg,ico,jpg}",  "**/*.{manifest,txt}"],` (example)

Comment: Does adding `html` to the regex not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different options for [configuring runtime routing and caching](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests); you can also create multiple routes with different strategies for each type of resource. [Routing based on the `request.destination` value](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes#cache_resources_based_on_resource_type) is a fairly robust approach.

I would avoid using a `CacheFirst` strategy for any URLs that are unversioned, since you don't have a great way of making sure it ever gets updated after you deploy changes. `StaleWhileRevalidate` or `NetworkFirst` is a safer strategy to use for URLs that don't contain hashes.

```js
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {StaleWhileRevalidate, NetworkFirst} from 'workbox-strategies';

registerRoute(
  // Match HTML document requests.
  ({request}) => request.destination === 'document',
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'html',
  })
);

registerRoute(
  // Match JS, CSS, and font requests.
  ({request}) => ['font', 'script', 'style'].includes(request.destination),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'resources',
  })
);
```